# Android progress bar not showing tje progress

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I am using countdown timer to show number of seconds in a textview
It work fine
Then i want to show the time progress in progress bar
It work fine if i define the seconds<100
But when i define int> 100
The progress bar not showing any progress while time countdown
**SOLVED**

Comment: for any `couter_int > 100` factor is 0 could that be a problem?

Comment: yes it could be the problem.. But is int factor 100/120 = 0?

Comment: when you divide a number from the number bigger than it , you get something with point, and an integer can't store point so it is rounded to 0, hence for any `counter_int > 100` factor will be zero

Comment: Ok. So what i can change in my code to make it not 0

Comment: dividend should be greater than or equal to divisor , so you can either increase the dividend or decrease the divisor in both cases it will not be zero

Comment: I cant increace the dividend or decreace the divisior

Comment: Ok friend.. I sovle my problem in another way

Comment: i got an answer if you want?